# Elemento de referência malformado XML NF Versão 4.0

Tags: c#, xml, nfe, xmldocument

Estou atualizando nosso programa de envio de notas de serviço (Sorocaba). Fazendo uma pesquisa rápida vi alguns comentários que após atualização do .Net Framework, a microsoft realizou uma correção na vulnerabilidades das Assinaturas e alguns carácteres especiais não podia ser usado. No entanto, ao tentar assinar estou recebendo um erro " elemento de referência malformado" , eu retirei os  "2 pontos ':'" da tag da prefeitura e passou, porém a prefeitura exige a TAG assinada no formato abaixo, com os 2 pontos **lote:**. O código é:

```
  // Create a reference to be signed
                            Reference reference = new Reference();
                            reference.Uri = "#lote1ABCDZ";
```

gostaria de saber como poderia proceder neste caso, onde a prefeitura exige algo que não pode ser usado mais pela Microsoft ou uma solução para isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver basta passar o ID em branco.

Por padrão o URI no reference vem NULL basta passar string.Empty e tudo fica certo.